# Sort adjacent pairs into row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, flatten

Let's say I have an array of paired integers

```
let pairs = [

    [6, 12],
    [7, 6],
    [8, 7],
    [9, 8],
    [12, 13],
    [13, 14],
    [14, 9]

];
```

All pairs creates chain by its nature, so you don't need to filter them.
So, the task is actually to build a chain from that, like

let output = [6, 12, 13, 14, 9, 8, 7];

It could be done by brute-forcing algorithm attached, but I am looking for more elegant solution.

```js
let pairs = [

    [6, 12],
    [7, 6],
    [8, 7],
    [9, 8],
    [12, 13],
    [13, 14],
    [14, 9]

];

let chain = [pairs[0][0], pairs[0][1]];
pairs.shift();

while(pairs.length !== 1){ 

    let j = null;

    for(let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){ 

        if(pairs[i][0] === chain[chain.length - 1]) { 

            chain.push(pairs[i][1]);
            j = i;
            break;
        }
        if(pairs[i][1] === chain[chain.length - 1]){

            chain.push(pairs[i][0]);
            j = i;
            break;

        }

    }

    if(j !== null) { pairs.splice(j, 1); }

}


console.log(chain);
```

Comment: You could use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to do this quite straightforwardly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Map to iterate only once:

```js
const pairs = [
    [6, 12],
    [7, 6],
    [8, 7],
    [9, 8],
    [12, 13],
    [13, 14],
    [14, 9]
];

const pairsMap = new Map(pairs)

const chain = [pairs[0][0]]
for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length - 1; i++) {
  const last = chain.at(-1)
  const peer = pairsMap.get(last)
  chain.push(peer)
}

console.log(chain)
```